# Проверить элемент на Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

Как на `Selenium Webdriver` выполнить проверку наличия элемента и, если элемент найден, то кликнуть по нему, а если нет, то продолжить выполнение программы?

Comment: id элемента известно?

Comment: Да, id элемента имеется

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```
boolean present;
try {
    driver.findElement(By.id(""));
    present = true;
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
   present = false;
}
```

Или:

```
if (!driver.findElement(By.id("...")).isEmpty())
{
     //Click on element
} else {
    //Element was not found
}
```